# How to remove a string from a Set<String>?

Tags: string, set

I have a `Set<String>` that contains a bunch of Strings.
How can I remove a certain `String` from a `Set<String>`?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
if(set.contains("arpit")) {
    set.remove("arpit");
}
```

Comment: Your check is unnecessary. If the set doesn't contain the `String`, `remove` will return false. No `Exception` would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you have:

```
Set<String> s;
.
.
.
s.remove("myString");
```

This will remove `"myString"` from your `Set` as `String`s are `singleton`s. There is no need to check if the `String` is in the `Set` because method `remove` will return `true` if something was removed and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In `javaScript`, It should be `delete` instead of `remove`.

```
set.remove("stringTobeRemoved")
```